# Laravel 4.x, Eloquent multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel, conditional-statements, where-clause

I've tried to this:

```
Product::where(['product_id' => $product->id, 'catalog_id' => $key])->first();
```

This isn't working at all. When I'm doing this:

```
Product:where('product_id', $product->id)->where('catalog_id', $key)->first();
```

It just works fine. I've searched in the documentation of Laravel,
and found nothing.

Is there any option to using the `where` function with an array in it ?

Comment: Either use a loop or extend 'QueryBuilder' and add the functionality yourself.

Comment: UPDATE: it is possible in the latest version of Laravel, like in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use where() individually.  If you want to dynamically building the query you can do something like:

```
$wheres = array('product_id' => $product->id, 'catalog_id' => $key);

$q = new Product;

foreach ( $wheres as $k => $v ) {
    $q = $q->where($k, $v); 
}

$products = $q->first();
```

Answer (score 4):

In fact we were all wrong ;)

**As of latest version of the framework you can do exactly what you wanted.**

Check this commit and update Laravel if you need that feature.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/87b267a232983abdac7c23c2dc6b1b270dd24b8a

Comment: 4 days ago though, should have been there since 4.1 at least. +1 for referencing something new and updating this question.

Answer (score 2):

```
Product::whereNested(function($query) use ($key, $product){
            $query->where('product_id', $product->id);
            $query->where('catalog_id', $key);
        })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's `where`s use an `and` condition by default:

```
$products = Product::where('this','=','that')->where('something','=','hello')->get();
```

is somewhat equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE this = 'that' AND something = 'hello';
```

You simply chain the `->where()` methods together. No need for an array.

If you want to use an `or` condition:

```
$products = Product::where('this','=','that')->orWhere('something','=','hello')->get();
```